# How to make Python read new lines and just lines?

Tags: python

I know that Python can read numbers like:

```
8
5
4
2
2
6
```

But I am not sure how to make it read it like:

```
8 5 4 2 2 6
```

Also, is there a way to make python read both ways? For example:

```
8 5 4
2
6
```

I think reading with new lines would be:

```
info = open("info.txt", "r")
lines = info.readlines()
info.close()
```

How can I change the code so it would read downwards and to the sides like in my third example above?

I have a program like this:

```
info = open("1.txt", "r")
lines = info.readlines()

numbers = []
for l in lines:
    num = int(l)
    numbers.append(str(num**2))
info.close()

info = open("1.txt", "w")
for num in numbers:
    info.write(num + "\n")
info.close()
```

How can I make the program read each number separately in new lines and in just lines?

Comment: I just wrote the code you have as your program, but for a different user about 45 minutes ago...

Comment: You can't do such thing, instead you can use a nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping them as strings:

```
with open("info.txt") as fobj:
    numbers = fobj.read().split()
```

Or, converting them to integers:

```
with open("info.txt") as fobj:
    numbers = [int(entry) for entry in fobj.read().split()]
```

This works with one number and several numbers per line.
This file content:

```
1
2
3 4 5
6
7
8 9 10
11
```

will result in this output for `numbers`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

This approach reads the whole file at once. Unless your file is really large this is fine.

Comment: That's what I'd do. Better also `map(int, ..)` it, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
info = open("1.txt", "r")
lines = info.readlines()

numbers = []
for line in lines:
    for num_str in line.split(' '):
        num = int(num_str)
        numbers.append(str(num**2))
info.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
info = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = info.readlines()
numbers = []
for l in lines:
    l = l.strip()
    lSplit = l.split(' ')
    if len(lSplit) == 1:
        num = int(l)
        numbers.append(str(num**2))
    else:
        for num in lSplit:
            num2 = int(num)
            numbers.append(str(num2**2))
print numbers
info.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
file_ = """
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 10 
11
12 13 14
"""


for number in file_ .split():
    print number

>>
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

Comment: Why the `[x for x in ...]`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann thanks for the comment, I forgot to make it to the original form after trying some thing else.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is with a generator that iterates over the lines, and, for each line, yields each of the numbers on it.  This works fine if there is only one number on the line (or none), too.

```
def numberfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as input:
         for line in input:
             for number in line.split():
                 yield int(number)
```

Then you can just write, for example:

```
for n in numberfile("info.txt"):
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care how many numbers per line, then you could try this to create the list of the squares of all the numbers.

I have simplified your code a bit by simply iterating over the open file using a `with` statement, but iterating over the `readlines()` result will work just as well (for small files - for large ones, this method doesn't require you to hold the whole content of the file in memory).

```
numbers = []
with open("1.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        nums = line.split()
        for n in nums:
            numbers.append(str(int(n)**2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another not yet posted way...

```
numbers = []
with open('info.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        numbers.extend(map(int, line.split()))
```